# htaccess redirect to another domain - specific pages then remaining to go to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am in the process of redirecting an old site to another domain. Using htaccess I have listed around 40-50 specific pages to be re-directed to it's equivalent on the new domain i.e:

```
redirect 301 /delivery.php http://www.newdomain.com/delivery/
redirect 301 /contact.php http://www.newdomain.com/contact-us/
redirect 301 /about.php http://www.newdomain.com/about/
redirect 301 /stores/finder.php http://www.newdomain.com/branch-finder/
...
```

I then have probably around 600-700 other links where i don't need them to go to a specific page, just the new domains homepage. Is there a way I can have a 'and all other pages go to homepage' line or command to just go to `http://www.newdomain.com`? Otherwise I will have to manually type and enter each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can have a 'and all other pages go to homepage' line

Yes sure you can have this rule as **your last rule**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+ http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Comment: I've just tried this but i get a 500 internal error when the code is included

Comment: Ah sorry there was a typo, it is fixed. Try it now.