# redirect certain pages to its equivalent in another domain, otherwise redirect to its homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to use htaccess to redirect certain pages to its equivalent in another domain, other pages redirect to homepage.

Like that:

- `http://old-domain.com/certain-page` redirected to: `http://new-domain.com/certain-page`
- `http://old-domain.com/another-certain-page` redirected to: `http://new-domain.com/another-certain-page`

Only these pages will be redirected, otherwise, pages have to be redirected to the new domain **home page**.

- `http://old-domain.com/non-certain-page` redirected to: `http://new-domain.com`

This is my try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^certain-page$ http://new-domain.com/certain-page [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^another-certain-page$ http://new-domain.com/another-certain-page [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But don't know how to **exclude** other pages.

Any help here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> But don't know how to exclude other pages

But you are already excluding the pages when you create specific rules for them. This should work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#redirect specific pages
RewriteRule ^certain-page$ http://new-domain.com/certain-page [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^another-certain-page$ http://new-domain.com/another-certain-page [R=301,L]

#Redirect everything else to homepage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Let me know how this works for you. If you need to clear you cache before trying these new rules.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be my answer. still testing it. But did you mean by clearing cache, cache for server?

Comment: No browser cache. Because sometimes old .htaccess rules are cached by the browser and the new rules don't seem to work. So when testing 301's it's best to clear your cache to make sure new rules take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765881/htaccess-redirect-to-another-domain-specific-pages-then-remaining-to-go-to-hom), thank to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)

With `redirect` without need to use `Rewrite` :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+ http://www.newdomain.com/
```

So, the answer can be also:

```
#Redirect specific pages
redirect 301 /certain-page http://new-domain.com/certain-page
redirect 301 /another-certain-page http://new-domain.com/another-certain-page

#Redirect everything else to homepage
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+ http://new-domain.com
```

Comment: upvoted because Redirect is actually the recommended way!